# complex relationship query with group by on many field

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to deal with a complex query. I want to select each object grouped by a field `type`.

In the same query (if it's possible) i want to select each value associated also grouped by a field `value` but there is a condition on this relationship.

Here a query who select all object which match the condition:

```
SELECT 
    Object.id
  FROM objects Object
    INNER JOIN elements Elements 
      ON Elements.object_id = Object.id
    INNER JOIN values Values 
      ON Values.element_id = Elements.id
  GROUP BY Object.id
  HAVING 
    SUM(Values.caracteristique_id = 82) = 1 
    AND 
    SUM(Values.caracteristique_id = 85) = 1
```

Now i'm searching to group the result set by field in Objects Table or/and Values Table

Comment: group by is a comma separated list, so just add to the list?

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work

Comment: What does not work (errors?)